# How to display a pandas dataframe in notebook with a column consisting of buttons widgets?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I have a pandas dataframe such as:

```
data = {
       'version': ['v1.0', 'v1.1', 'v1.2'],
       'Start Time (UTC)': ['2021-01-01 10:00', '2021-02-01 11:00', '2021-03-01 12:00'],
       'status': ['active', 'inactive', 'active']
   }
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I can display it nicely in my notebook cell using

```
from IPython.display import display

display(df)
```

I want to add a column consisting only of buttons, of exact type `from ipywidgets import Button`. How to do that?

I tried:

```
df["Logs"] = df["Start Time (UTC)"].apply(
        lambda tsp: Button(
            description="show below",
            icon="sort-down",
            tooltip=str(tsp),
        ))
```

but this displays the raw string of the button, i.e. `Button(description='show below', icon='sort-do...` and not an interactive button.